# Is a gRPC client/stub usage across goroutines

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I'm experimenting with Protobuf and gRPC and was going through the Go basics tutorial: https://www.grpc.io/docs/languages/go/basics/

From what I could see in the documentation about the [ClientConn](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#ClientConn) it seems that it is safe to use the same ClientConn concurrently. But I can't anything about the stub/client that one creates...

Say I was receiving data via HTTP POST requests and I wanted to forward that data via gRPC as protobuf and then respond to the HTTP request. Should I create a client/stub every time I process a HTTP request, or can I create the client/stub when setting up the HTTP server and pass in the client/stub when setting up HTTP Handlers?

Example: I assume this is okay

```
var opts []grpc.DialOption
conn, err := grpc.Dial("127.0.0.1:1234", opts...)
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}
defer conn.Close()
grpcService := service.Service{GRPC: conn}
http.HandleFunc("/", util.ValidateRequest(grpcService.HandleRoot))

// listen to port
http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", viper.GetString("server.address"), viper.GetInt32("server.port")), nil)
```

but what about this

```
var opts []grpc.DialOption
conn, err := grpc.Dial("127.0.0.1:1234", opts...)
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}
defer conn.Close()
client := pb.NewEventShipperClient(conn)
grpcService := service.Service{GRPC: conn, Client: client}
http.HandleFunc("/", util.ValidateRequest(grpcService.HandleRoot))

// listen to port
http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", viper.GetString("server.address"), viper.GetInt32("server.port")), nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread safety ("is it safe to run this concurrently") is covered in the [Generated-code reference](https://www.grpc.io/docs/languages/go/generated-code/):

> **Thread-safety:** note that client-side RPC invocations and server-side RPC handlers are thread-safe and are meant to be run on concurrent goroutines. But also note that for individual streams, incoming and outgoing data is bi-directional but serial; so e.g. individual streams do not support concurrent reads or concurrent writes (but reads are safely concurrent with writes).

So, yes, methods on the `struct` returned by `pb.NewEventShipperClient(conn)` can be called concurrently.

You can also check this yourself by looking at the implementation of `pb.NewEventShipperClient`. Currently (I guess this may change) the only member variable will be an interface (`cc grpc.ClientConnInterface` - implemented by `*ClientConn`) with each method using the connection to `Invoke` a gRPC call.

Please note, however, that you need to be careful in your implementation of `service.Service` to ensure it is also threadsafe and note the caveat regarding streams.